# Dropdown to filter group in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm developing a D3 force layout similar to the link below, but a bit more complex.

https://www.d3indepth.com/force-layout/

I have added a drop down menu to filter the searches. Each group of circles represents the shareholders of a company. My goal is that when selecting an option from the menu, all its shares in the different companies (groups) changed color.

[image]

I'm doing something wrong because I can only visualize the black circles in one of these groups. Do you know what I'm failing?

[image]

```
function main() {
    createSVG()
    build()
}
  
let svg
let g
let circles
let screenWidth = 1200
let screenHeight = 500
  
function createSVG() {
    const container = d3.select('.container')
    svg = container.append('svg')
            .attr('id', 'canvas')
            .attr('width', screenWidth)
            .attr('height', screenHeight)
            .style("cursor", "pointer")
            .style('background-color', 'grey')
        .append("g")
            .attr("transform", `translate(${5}, ${250})`)
}
  
async function build() {  
  
  //Load data
  const data = await d3.json("./data/delivery.json")
  
  //Create scales and positions
  const colorScale = ['orange', 'lightblue', 'purple', 'yellow', 'green', "red", "black"];
  const xCenter = [100, 300, 500, 700, 900, 1100, 1300];
  
  //Create scale to match node size
  const scale = d3.scaleSqrt()
    .domain([0, 50])
    .range([0, 70])
  
  //Configure forces between nodes 
  const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data)
      .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(5))
      .force('x', d3.forceX().x(d => xCenter[d.group]))
      .force('collision', d3.forceCollide().radius(d => scale(d.value)))
      .on('tick', createCircles)
  
  //Create the tooltip
  const tooltip = d3.select('.tooltip')
  .style('position', 'absolute')
  .style('opacity', 0)
  .style('background-color', 'white')           
  
  //Data for the button
  let dataButton = ["Baillie Gifford", "Sequoia", "Morgan Stanley", "Goldman Sachs", "Vanguard", "T.Rower Price", "J.P. Morgan", "Fidelity", "Norges Bank", "BlackRock", "Capital Group", "Sands Capital"]
  
  //Create the button
  let dropdownButton = d3.select(".container")
      .append('select')
  
  dropdownButton
      .selectAll('myOptions')
          .data(dataButton)
      .enter()
          .append('option')
      .text(function(d) {return d})
      .attr("value", function(d) {return d})
  
  //Create circles and set mouse events
  function createCircles() {
    circles = d3.select('svg g')
        .selectAll('circle')
        .data(data)
        .join('circle')
        .attr('class', d => d.name.replace(/ /g, ""))
        .attr('r', d => scale(d.value))
        .style('fill', d => colorScale[d.group])
        .attr('cx', d => d.x)
        .attr('cy', d => d.y)
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            tooltip
            .transition()
            .duration(100)
            .style("opacity", 0.9)
            .text(d.name + ":" + " " + d.value + "%")
        })
        .on("mousemove", function(){return tooltip.style("top", (d3.event.pageY + 20)+"px").style("left",(d3.event.pageX + 2)+"px")})
        .on("mouseout", function(){return tooltip.transition().duration(100).style("opacity", 0)})
    }
  
  function updateChart(value) {

    let newData = data.filter( d => {return d.name === value})
    console.log(newData)
    circles
        .data(newData)
        .transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style('fill', 'black')
    }
  
  dropdownButton.on("change", function (d) {
      let selectedOption = d3.select(this).property("value")
      updateChart(selectedOption)
    })
}
  
main()
```

Comment: Can you post a valid link to your `delivery.json` file (you can do it with https://jsonbin.io/) and provide a working snippet or fiddle?

Comment: Here it's: https://api.jsonbin.io/b/60c732a5a8bf076b5f67295c